# I have followed the videos on setting up configurable items but the items do not appear on my site?

Tags: configurable-product

[image]I am building an online wine shop and it is coming along very nicely. [enter link description here](http://www.cellar2door.com)

I want to be able to have one wine name example Penfolds Cab Sav and then be able to have different years and then different prices for those years. (like someone might have different sizes for a tv that was the same model and hence different prices)

I have searched and found various solutions for configurable products. I created an attribute year but each time I try and create a new product it does not seem to work for me. I have tried it several times and the products don't display on the site. Does anyone know a good tutorial as the ones i have followed have not resulted in me getting the right result.

Or does anyone know how to do it and can advise me. I have attached a screen shot of my products list that shows the products I have created but they are not appearing on the site.

I followed all 4 videos step by step. I also note the price in the configurable items is using the price from both items the main one and the new one. I also note that the main item does not allow me to [image]put a quantity so would that be stopping it from showing up on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from your screenshot that the product has not been assigned to your website. Make sure you set this and ensure it is associated to a category.

Comment: Hi Eric, sorry I did that after I had taken the screen shot and it still does not show. Also for some reason the prices are duplicating from the main product to the configured products

Comment: Hi Eric I just tried again adding the product in default and has the same result. Prices appear doubled in back end and products don't appear in front end. I put a new screen shot into the original message.

Comment: I'm not really following what you mean by the prices are doubled in the backend. Are you running any 3rd party extensions that affect the products? As for getting the configurable products to show go check the following. On the inventory tab, mark availability as 'In Stock'. Make sure there is a simple product associated in the configurable product. Make sure the simple product has availability marked as 'In Stock'. Re-index (System > Index Management > Select All > Submit.

Comment: Hi Eric thanks for the input I had missed the instock option. What i mean about the prices is seen here http://www.cellar2door.com/index.php/reds/chile/montes-folly-syrah-38.html It putting the prices from each item together with the original product price.

Comment: Hi Eric its ok worked it out now. Many thanks for the help.